# Wordpress - permission denied

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I have a website and I'm passing it to another server. I using permalink `day and name`. When I try to access to any page I receive this message:

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

If I change the permalink to `plain` it works but I need to set it in `day and name`

I don't know what kind of problem is that.

How can I solve that?

Comment: A permalink cannot contains any space, try to set `day-and-name`

Comment: Try to change and revert the permalinks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at chmod in wordpress files/dirs 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

OTher thing may me htaccess. 
https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

Answer (score 0):

As My Experience with WordPress I Advice First Set Permalink again default one ... and check is everything working ? Also try in build other permalink options is that working?

If above both working then write your custom permalink ..
If above booth not working then Check Rewrite option of domain it must Allow **.htaccess** to fix just replace .htaccess file https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This simple tip will fix your issue ... DONT FORGET TO CLEAR CACHES

## Cheers